# Should I close connection after every insert batch?

Tags: asyncpg

I need to insert a couple of dozen rows remotely once every 10 seconds. I am not sure whether I should use `async with connection` around each insert, closing the connection and re-opening every 10s, or just `await conn = ...` once and have a handle on an open connection forever.

Please explain at what point the decision would change, based on other numbers of rows and insert frequency.